# How to get Minecraft Mixins to work in an intellij dev environment

Tags: intellij-idea, mixins, minecraft-forge

I am trying to make a minecraft mod in forge. I added mixins (0.8.3) using gradle, it works when I run it through the official minecraft launcher, however when I try to run it through Intellij using the defualt forge run configurations, it doesn't work. At first, I thought it could be that I didn't ad"-Dfml.coreMods.load=(my mixin loader)" to the VM options. So I tried adding that to the VM optionsand it still doesn't work. I have tried downgrading my mixins version, upgrading it to a snapshot, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my Gradle version (4.9) was too old. Updated to 5.6.4 and it all works now!